# Prove that $ a^2+b^2+c^2 \le a^3 +b^3 +c^3 $

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, tangent-line-method, muirhead-inequality

If $ a,b,c $ are three positive real numbers and $ abc=1 $ then prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \le a^3 +b^3 +c^3 $

I got $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge 3$ which can be proved $ a^2 +b^2+c^2\ge a+b+c $. From here how can I proceed to the results? Please help me to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, $a,b,c $ are positive real numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same as proving that
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(abc)^{1/3}\le a^3+b^3+c^3$$
for all positive $a$, $b$, $c$. This is AM/GM. We get
$$a^{7/3}b^{1/3}c^{1/3}\le\frac{7a^3+b^3+c^3}9$$
applying AM/GM to seven copies of $a^{3}$ and one each of $b^{3}$ and $c^{3}$. Cyclicly
permute and add.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that $$\sum_{cyc}\left(a^3-a^{\frac{7}{3}}b^{\frac{1}{3}}c^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\geq0$$ and since $$(3,0,0)\succ\left(\frac{7}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right),$$ it's true by Muirhead.

Answer (score 1):

Also, we can use a Tangent Line method:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2)=\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2-\ln{a})\geq0$$ because easy to see that
$$a^3-a^2-\ln{a}\geq0:$$
$$(a^3-a^2-\ln{a})'=3a^2-2a-\frac{1}{a}=$$
$$=\frac{3a^3-3a^2+a^2-a+a-1)}{a}=\frac{(a-1)(3a^2+a+1)}{a},$$
which gives $a_{min}=1$ and we are done!